# How to run SQL Server query that will make other queries run more slowly

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012

This is going to sound like a hacker question, but is there a query that I can run in SQL Server that will chew up CPU time to make other queries run more slowly?

The reason I ask is because I am trying to reproduce a timeout error that happens in production.  In the Dev environment, SQL Server never gives such a timeout error, so I am seeking a way to slow SQL Server down with some queries that do nothing but chew up CPU time.

I have tried setting `Timeout=1` in the connection string, but the exception is still not thrown.

Comment: you need to set the timeout in the ADO.NET command, not the connection string

Comment: @MitchWheat The one in the connection string does not get applied to the connection?

Comment: The one in the connection string refers to how much time can elapse for a connection to be made. The timeout in a command refers to how long the command can run.

Comment: @MitchWheat, Thank you very much, very helpful.

Answer (score 1):

You could row multiply and summarize across large sequences using a tally function and it will peg the cpu at 100%.  If you'd like it to run longer add some zeros.

Tally function

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[fnTally]
/**********************************************************************************************************************
    Jeff Moden Script on SSC: https://www.sqlservercentral.com/scripts/create-a-tally-function-fntally
**********************************************************************************************************************/
        (@ZeroOrOne BIT, @MaxN BIGINT)
RETURNS TABLE WITH SCHEMABINDING AS 
 RETURN WITH
  H2(N) AS ( SELECT 1 
               FROM (VALUES
                     (1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1)
                    ,(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1)
                    ,(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1)
                    ,(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1)
                    ,(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1)
                    ,(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1)
                    ,(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1)
                    ,(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1)
                    ,(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1)
                    ,(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1)
                    ,(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1)
                    ,(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1)
                    ,(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1)
                    ,(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1)
                    ,(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1)
                    ,(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1)
                    )V(N))            --16^2 or 256 rows
, H4(N) AS (SELECT 1 FROM H2 a, H2 b) --16^4 or 65,536 rows
, H8(N) AS (SELECT 1 FROM H4 a, H4 b) --16^8 or 4,294,967,296 rows
            SELECT N = 0 WHERE @ZeroOrOne = 0 UNION ALL
            SELECT TOP(@MaxN)
                   N = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY N)
              FROM H8
;
```

Queries

```
/* 4 seconds -- Standard S2 @50 DTU */
with big_cte as(
select
  n1.n,
  count(*) n2_count
from 
  dbo.fntally(1, 10000000) n1
 cross join
  dbo.fntally(1, 10000000) n2
group by
  n1.n)
select count(*) from big_cte;

/* 47 seconds -- Standard S2 @50 DTU */
with big_cte as(
select
  n1.n,
  count(*) n2_count
from 
  dbo.fntally(1, 100000000) n1
 cross join
  dbo.fntally(1, 100000000) n2
group by
  n1.n)
select count(*) from big_cte;
```

Answer (score 1):

**Slow query coming right up!**. @SteveC's answer is excellent and will certainly do the trick. I *literally* wrapped up [an article about the code below](https://codingblackarts.com/2020/11/30/how-to-find-strings-longer-than-8k-in-sql-server-part-1/) 15 minutes ago so I couldn't resist. This query is going to be slower than a heard of fat, old, 3-legged turtles crossing a wide street made out of melted marshmallows. It will also cause an [intra query parallelism deadlock](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/4089473/kb4089473-better-intra-query-parallelism-deadlock-troubleshooting-in-s) which ruins the fun for everyone. You'll need a copy of [dbo.NGrams2B](https://www.sqlservercentral.com/wp-content/uploads/2019/05/Attachment%201%20-%20NGrams%20Functions.sql) (the fastest VARCHAR(MAX) N-Grams function on the planet, but not today.)

```
DECLARE @Match VARCHAR(MAX) = REPLICATE(CAST('X' AS VARCHAR(MAX)),150000),
        @Junk1 VARCHAR(MAX) = REPLICATE(CAST('Z' AS VARCHAR(MAX)),10000011),
        @Junk2 VARCHAR(MAX) = REPLICATE(CAST('#' AS VARCHAR(MAX)),2000000000);

DECLARE @SearchText VARCHAR(MAX) = @Match,
        @SomeString VARCHAR(MAX) = @Junk1+@Match+@Junk2;

SELECT ItemIndex = ISNULL(MAX(f.ItemIndex),0)
FROM
(
  -- Returns the first position of @SearchText
  SELECT TOP(1) ng.Position
  FROM     dbo.ngrams(@SomeString,LEN(@SearchText)) AS ng
  WHERE    ng.Token = @SearchText
  ORDER BY ng.Position
) AS f(ItemIndex)
OPTION (QUERYTRACEON 8649);
```

Godspeed my friend!

Comment: Love it! Thanks Alan